# Get HID report Descriptor from .pcap file

Tags: c++, usb, mouse, pcap, hid

I am building a C++ app on windows that should reinterpret USB data stream captured by [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and [USBPCap](https://desowin.org/usbpcap/index.html) stored into a `.pcap` file. I am currently having trouble to get `HID Report descriptor`, so then i would be able to interpret data that mouse sends to the host.

The site [USB Made Simple](http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/index.html) has been a great source of information so far, and i have also read a tons of tutorials how to write your own HID Report descriptor in order to understand them. But what i need is to retrieve one from current data flow.

According to wireshark, mouse is sending me a `DEVICE DESCRIPTOR` ([example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGLJv.png)), after that it sends `CONFIGURATION DESCRIPTOR` with its `INTERFACE, HID` and `ENDPOINT DESCRIPTORS` ([example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYI45.png)).

According to value of `wDescriptorLength` in `HID DESCRIPTOR`, there should be `HID REPORT DESCRIPTOR` of length 56, but there is not. After this there is only `ENDPOINT DESCRIPTOR` of length 7 and another `INTERFACE` and `HID DESCRIPTOR` of total lenght 18.

Is there any way to get `HID REPORT DESCRIPTOR` from this or am I missing something out ?

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get `HID REPORT DESCRIPTOR` from this or am I missing something out ?

Don't know about you but for me that looks like Wireshark/USBPCap is missing something.
If you compare it with mine example it looks like entries with `USBHID` protocol are missing in your part.

[image]

Please check your Wireshark version or if you don't have enabled any filters in capture configuration.

If you click 'gear' icon on the left side of USBPcap interface you can check your current settings:

[image: USBPcap settings]

**Important note**:
Despite fact that "Inject already connected devices descriptors..." is checked it doesn't work for me like I would expect and to capture Report Descriptor you have to reconnect device: unplug USB-HID device -> Start capture -> Plug in USB device -> Now you can stop capture.

Comment: With what did you capture this ? Are you also using USBPCAP with Wireshark ?

Comment: Yes, USBPcap.sys/USBPcapCMD.exe both in version 1.5.4.0 and Wireshark 3.2.6, Windows 10 64bit / 1909

Comment: Me too. Did you just copied USBPcapCMD.exe to a Wireshark/extcap directory, and then do all the capture inside Wireshark ?

Comment: No, only during installation of Wireshark I've checked 'Install USBPcap driver' and it is working out of the box. In the list with interfaces is new position `USBPcap`.

Comment: What do you mean out of the box ? How do you start the capturing ?

Comment: I mean that USBPcap is visible just as additional 'network' interface in wireshark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221642/discussion-between-peter-and-n3vermind).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Win32 HID-parse utilities to do this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/preparsed-data

See here for an example of use, where the HID report is accessed using `WM_INPUT`:
https://github.com/supersmo/Using-Raw-Input-API-to-Process-Joystick-Input

...in particular these methods:

```
// determine buffer size required
CHECK( GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInput->header.hDevice, RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA, NULL, &bufferSize) == 0 );

// allocate buffer
CHECK( pPreparsedData = (PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, bufferSize) );

// determine the usages etc
CHECK( (int)GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInput->header.hDevice, RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA, pPreparsedData, &bufferSize) >= 0 );

// Button caps
CHECK( HidP_GetCaps(pPreparsedData, &Caps) == HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS )

// Value caps
CHECK( pValueCaps = (PHIDP_VALUE_CAPS)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, sizeof(HIDP_VALUE_CAPS) * Caps.NumberInputValueCaps) );
capsLength = Caps.NumberInputValueCaps;
CHECK( HidP_GetValueCaps(HidP_Input, pValueCaps, &capsLength, pPreparsedData) == HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS )
```

Another thing to look at is the `ReactOS hidusb source` which can be found (today) here:
https://doxygen.reactos.org/dd/d06/hidusb_8c_source.html

...pay particular attention to e.g. `HidUsb_GetReportDescriptor`

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand how `Raw Input` works, but what I am confused about is what represents `LPARAM` in my program. All I do is reading a `.pcap` file. I tried to convert`const unsigned char*` which represents my additional packet data(data send to host during `BULK_OR_INTERRUPT TRANSFER` which come after all header data) to `PRAWINPUT`, so that I dont have to use `GetRawInputData`, but that didnt give me something meaningful. Did I misunderstand something in your answer or am I missing something out ?